# Как вставить в функцию логин и пароль, которые ввел пользователь в телеграмм боте? API называется: NetSchool API

Tags: python, aiogram, асинхронность, async-await

```
Хочу сделать вывод данных с NetSchool API, но почему-то не получается! Если не сложно, можете пожалуйста помочь?
Сохраняю все введенные данные в базу SQLite. После этого хочу вставить логин и пароль в поля авторизации в асинхронной функции API! Можете пожалуйста подсказать, что я делаю не так?

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'bot_message.<locals>.main' was never awaited
  handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Использую API: [NetSchool API](https://netschoolapi.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/)

В директории проекта лежат вот такие файлы:
1) database.db
2) db.py
3) main.py
4) markups.py


# **main.py:**

    import logging
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
    import markups as nav
    from db import Database
    import asyncio
    from netschoolapi import NetSchoolAPI
    
    
    TOKEN = ""
    
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    
    db = Database('database.db')
    
    
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    async def start(message: types.Message):
        if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)): #Проверка: Если такого id пользователя нет в базе, то регистрируем
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Укажите ваш логин и пароль от Электронного Журнала через пробел.\nПример: ИвановТ ivanov2008")
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы уже зарегистрированы!", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
    
    @dp.message_handler()
    async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
            if message.text == ' ПРОФИЛЬ': #Отправка данных из БД
                user_nickname = "Ваш ник: " + db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id)
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, user_nickname)
    
                user_password = "Ваш пароль: " + db.get_password(message.from_user.id)
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, user_password)
    
            elif message.text == 'ЭЖ':
                async def main():
                    ns = NetSchoolAPI('https://net-school.cap.ru/')
                    await ns.login(
                        db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id),
                        db.get_password(message.from_user.id),
                        511,
                    )
                    info = await ns.diary()
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, info)
    
                    await ns.logout()
                asyncio.run(main())
            else:
                if db.get_signup(message.from_user.id) == "setnickname": #Проверка на успешную запись в БД
                    if (len(message.text) > 60):
                        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Пароль и логин не могут превышать 60 символов")
                    else:
                        text = message.text.split(' ')
                        login = text[0]
                        passw = text[1]
                        db.set_nickname(message.from_user.id, login)
                        db.set_password(message.from_user.id, passw)
                        db.set_signup(message.from_user.id, "done")
                        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Регистрация прошла успешно!",
                                               reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
                else:
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я вас не понял! :( \nВоспользуйтесь пожалуйста кнопками!")
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)


`

# **markups.py: **
`

    from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
    
    btnProfile = KeyboardButton(' ПРОФИЛЬ')
    btnSub = KeyboardButton('ЭЖ')
    
    mainMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    mainMenu.add(btnProfile, btnSub)

`


# **db.py: **

`

    import sqlite3
    
    
    class Database:
        def __init__(self, db_file):
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    
        def add_user(self, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
    
        def user_exists(self, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
                return bool(len(result))
    
        def set_nickname(self, user_id, nickname):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `nickname` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (nickname, user_id,))
    
        def set_password(self, user_id, password):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (password, user_id,))
    
        def get_signup(self, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT `signup` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
                for row in result:
                    signup = str(row[0])
                return signup
    
        def set_signup(self, user_id, signup):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `signup` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (signup, user_id,))
    
        def get_nickname(self, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT `nickname` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
                for row in result:
                    nickname = str(row[0])
                return nickname
    
        def get_password(self, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
                for row in result:
                    password = str(row[0])
                return password

`
```